# JQuery - scroll using the element itself

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a "slider" (a div with some divs, but the overflow-x is hidden), but use the object itself instead a scrollbar. A made the code below, where works "a little" well, but the "scrollLeft" always start in 0:

```
var clicked = false, clickX;

$(document).on({
    'mousemove': function(e) {
        clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
    },
    'mousedown': function(e) {
        clicked = true;
        clickX = e.pageX;
    },
    'mouseup': function() {
        clicked = false;
    }
});

var box02_planos_hover = false;
var box02_planos = null;

$('.box02-planos').hover(function(e){
    box02_planos_hover = true;
    box02_planos = $(this);
    console.log(e.pageX - box02_planos.offset().left);
},function(){
    box02_planos_hover = false;
});

updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    if(box02_planos_hover){
        $(box02_planos).scrollLeft(clickX - e.pageX);
    }
}
```

If I change the line:

```
$(box02_planos).scrollLeft($(box02_planos).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX));
```

It works a little too, but too fast. How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sctf0o63/